# How scrape items from 2 different sections?

Tags: python, mysql, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

im new with Scrapy and web crawling and I've been working on the page www.mercadolibre.com.mx I have to get (from the startpage) some data (descripton and prices) about the produtcs displayed in there. Here is my items.py:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class PruebaMercadolibreItem(Item):
    producto = Field()
    precio = Field()
```

And here is my spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from prueba_mercadolibre.items import PruebaMercadolibreItem

class MLSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "mlspider"
    allowed_domains = ["mercadolibre.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mercadolibre.com.mx"]

    def parse (self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//div[@class='item-data']")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = PruebaMercadolibreItem()
            item["producto"] = titles.select("p[@class='tit    le']/@title").extract()
            item["precio"] = titles.select("span[@class='ch-price']/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

The problem is that I get the same results in when I change this line:

```
    titles = hxs.select("//div[@class='item-data']")
```

To this:

```
    titles = hxs.select("//div[@class='item-data'] | //div[@class='item-data item-data-mp']")
```

And Im not getting the same data as when I use the first line.

Can anyone help me? do I have any errorin my xPath selection?

Also I cant find a good tutorial for using MySQL with scrapy, I would appreciate any help. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use `contains` if you want to get all `div` tags containing `item-data` class:

```
titles = hxs.select("//div[contains(@class, 'item-data')]")
```

Also, you have other problems in the spider:

- the loop, you are overriding the `titles`
- class name in `producto` xpath should be `title`, not `tit    le`
- you probably don't want to have lists in `Field` values, get the first items out of the [`extract`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.extract)ed lists
- `HtmlXPathSelector` is deprecated, use [`Selector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector) instead
- `select()` is deprecated, use [`xpath()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.xpath) instead
- `BaseSpider` has been renamed to [`Spider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=spider#spider)

Here's the code with modifications:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from prueba_mercadolibre.items import PruebaMercadolibreItem    


class MLSpider(Spider):
    name = "mlspider"
    allowed_domains = ["mercadolibre.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mercadolibre.com.mx"]

    def parse (self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'item-data')]")
        for title in titles:
            item = PruebaMercadolibreItem()
            item["producto"] = title.xpath("p[@class='title']/@title").extract()[0]
            item["precio"] = title.xpath("span[@class='ch-price']/text()").extract()[0]
            yield item
```

Example items from the output:

```
{'precio': u'$ 35,000', 'producto': u'Cuatrimoto, Utv De 500cc 4x4 ,moto , Motos, Atv ,'}
{'precio': u'$ 695', 'producto': u'Reloj Esp\xeda Camara Oculta Video Hd 16 Gb! Sony Compara.'}
```

Comment: Ok, thx for the tips, I didn't knew a lot of stuff but, my real question here was if I could get data from diferent sources, for example I want data from both "//div[contains(@class, 'item-data')]" and //div[contains(@class, 'item-data item-data-mp')] how do I do that?

Comment: @AlexLezama the code I've posted is already doing that. It handles both cases with the help of `contains`.

Comment: umm thx a lot. I still have some doubts, in the page www.mercadolibre.com.mx I can see more than 24 items and this code always returns me just 24 do you know why?

Comment: @AlexLezama yeah, I got it now. The situation is a bit more complex, `item-data-mp` items are not present in the html scrapy gets since there is a javascript function involved in building the web page. I'm afraid it won't be easy to get other items (with `item-data-mp` class) from the page.

Comment: well if you don't know how to do it then im not going to be able to solve it in this moment, also do you know where can a I find a good tutorial on how to pass info from this spider to MySQL database? Im new with scrapy and I'm not used to all the sintax and stuff I've read in other places I'd realy aprecciate any help. BTW I'm using Windows 8

Comment: @AlexLezama you need to create a [pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html). For example, you can take [this one](http://snipplr.com/view/66986/mysql-pipeline/) as a template. There are other examples of mysql pipelines on the web.

Comment: And how do i run the pipeline once I've written it?

Comment: @AlexLezama you need to configure it in `settings`. I suggest going throw the [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#scrapy-tutorial) for better understanding how scrapy works. Really worth it. Hope that helps.